# Trying to get the insertion point of a textView macOS

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to get the insertion point of a textView macOS

```
// Get insertion point position
            if let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange {
                cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
            }
```

I get this error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')

I use a similar code in iOS and it works, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if let` assumes that the right side of the assignment is an optional.  `selectedRange` doesn't return an optional; you should be able to use it directly without testing it.